# run a script from the console on linux

Tags: php, linux, command

I want to run a php script on linux from the console, but I do not know the command. the equivalent on Windows is that there (`START http://localhost/project/update.php`).
I do not know if it is possible to run this script in the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php is the command to run php script .

**php -f filename.php**

Answer (score 3):

Yes off course it's possible.

```
php -f phpfile.php
```

Considering your phpfile.php contains -

```
<?php
$item = 3;
echo "item : $item";
```

It will print **item : 3** on command line.

Answer (score 2):

```
php -f filename.php
php -a #for all options to see
```

[for more info](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php).